# Firebase: createUser is undefined

Tags: firebase, browserify

New to Firebase, and I'm trying to create a user. I'm following the instructions for [email and password authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html), and I've enabled "Email & Password" in my Firebase account under "Login & Authentication."

When calling `createUser()` it returns as `undefined`.

```
ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com');

ref.createUser({
  email    : 'test@test.com',
  password : '1234'
}, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("User created successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  }
});
```

The `ref` object looks like:

```
E {
  Ca: undefined
  Ea: undefined
  Wa: undefined
  fa: undefined
  m: ze
  path: F
  ya: undefined
}
```

So I'm not sure I'm instantiating `ref` properly or what.

I'm using the [client-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-firebase) in a browserify stack.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not sure what version they based `client-firebase` on, but it indeed doesn't seem to have a `createUser` method. https://github.com/cloud-walker/client-firebase It also hasn't been updated in 6 months, while Firebase have released quite some updates since.  You might want to reconsider your choice of client and go with the official one from Firebase itself: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/.

Comment: Ah, well that's a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase updated api and removed callback function second parameter because of some security issues.

Read more details: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/api.md#createuseremail-password-callback